# Difference between clone and deepClone

Tags: apex

I'm having a hard time visualising the difference between shallow clone and deep clone in apex, for example

```
Account acct = [SELECT Id, Name, Rating, ParentId FROM Account WHERE Id = '0010O00001qEu5cQAC'][0];

//specifying false for isDeepClone parameter
Account acctDeepClone = acct.clone(false,false);
acctDeepClone.Name = 'DeepClone2';

update acct;
```

Changing the account name of the shallow clone and then updating the original does nothing to the original, the original name remains.

Also, I cannot update **acctDeepClone** because it doesn't have an Id field.

If I change my code to the following

```
Account acct = [SELECT Id, Name, Rating, ParentId FROM Account WHERE Id = '0010O00001qEu5cQAC'][0];

//specifying true for isDeepClone parameter
Account acctDeepClone = acct.clone(false,true);
acctDeepClone.Name = 'DeepClone2';

update acct;
```

I see the exact same behaviour as in the first snippet, the original account is never updated, and I cannot update the cloned version.

Can someone please show a concrete example (no theory) of how these two really look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It affects the referenced objects.

If you have a lookup / master detail and you touch the info there and update afterwards, you will see the difference.

In the example below, if you play with `false` or `true` you will see that the Parent account is modified or not (respectively)

```
// Preparation of Hierarchy
Account a1 = new Account(Name = 'Acc 1');
insert a1;

Account a11 = new Account(Name = 'Acc 1.1', ParentId = a1.Id);
insert a11;

// fetch child 1
a11 = [SELECT Name, parent.Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :a11.Id];

// clone it to create a12
Account a12 = a11.clone(false,true);

// touch parent on clone
a12.parent.Name = 'Acc 1 FROM 2';

// update parent info from original child
// if you put true, it will keep 'Acc 1' 
// if you put false it will have 'Acc 1 FROM 2'
update a11.parent;
```